# Analytical solution of the ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, sturm-liouville

Consider the following boundary value problem.
\begin{equation*}
    \begin{split}
        u=x^2u'+\frac{x^3}{3}u'', &\quad u(0)=A, \quad u(1)=B
    \end{split}
\end{equation*}
Is there any analytical method to solve the problem? According to WolframAlpha one can write the equation as a Sturm-Liouville equation as:
\begin{equation*}
    \begin{split}
        (x^3u')'&=3u
    \end{split}
\end{equation*}
or as an Emden-Fowler one as:
\begin{equation*}
    \begin{split}
        xu''+3u'=\frac{3u}{x^2}
    \end{split}
\end{equation*}
but I can find no methods to solve the problem analytically. I would be very grateful if someone explains some method to solve the problem.

Comment: Since we are already using WolframAlpha, it gives solutions in terms of modified Bessel functions:
$
u(x) = c_1\frac{I_2(2\sqrt{3}x^{-1/2})}{x} + c_2\frac{K_2(2\sqrt{3}x^{-1/2})}{x}.
$ One then needs to do some work to figure out if either term is blowing up at the origin and apply the BCs accordingly.

Comment: The BVP seems to be singular at $x=0$, so not just any boundary condition can be applied. The only finite boundary condition there is $u(0)=0$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

$$u=x^2u'+\frac{x^3}{3}u''$$
$$u=\frac v x \quad \implies \quad \left(\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{3}\right) v-\frac{1}{3} x \left(x
   v''+v'\right)=0$$ looks like a [Bessel differential equation](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/BesselDifferentialEquation.html).

Comment: We both mentioned the approach of using Bessel equations.  I didn’t necessarily recognize it as a Bessel equation itself, but I gave the step by step process on how you may solve it, without any explicit details with the problem itself.  (However, I took a class doing this a few years ago, so it is definitely not on the top of my mind)

Answer (score 1):

I’m not sure if it works for this specific case, but think of this like a Bessel Function solution, in that we want to “guess” the solution to be some polynomial.  So we choose an attempt to let the function be the sum from a constant to some finite power $n$ of $x$ (or if you want to find a harder class of solutions, which this might be a part of: use an infinite series denoted as a power series) with coefficients $c_0$ through $c_n$, even further if it is harder you can work the sum backwards to negative powers of $x$.  Then solve for what the coefficients need to be in order for this ODE to be solved.  It may not necessarily be a nice pattern, so it could look like it isn’t converging, which means you can approximate the ODE numerically by cutting off the power series at a specified $n$ with the particular accuracy you desire.  Sorry if this seems convoluted, but if you need clarification just send a comment and I’ll try to respond with anything that might help make this clearer.